# Asp.net Substring to get the formatted date

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net what I am trying to do is, I am getting the date as `20141024` (`yyyyMMdd`)(string) I want to get the substring from `20141024` as `a=2014`, `b=10` and `c=24` so that I can concatenate it and get it in my way as (`a&"/"&b&"/"&c`) that will be `24/10/2014`
when i tried to do `str.Substring(3,5)` it gives error.

Answer (score 3):

The way to go here is to parse your input to a `DateTime` object and then output it in the desired format:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
result = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyymmdd", provider);
result.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

See [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you achieve your goal,it's a C# example code

```
string date = "20141024";

string a = date.Substring(0, 4);
string b = date.Substring(4, 2);
string c = date.Substring(6, 2);
```